# android HttpResponse always dies second time it is called

Tags: java, android, apache, drupal, httpresponse

I have a strange glitch where I cannot make the same network call twice.

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, new BasicHttpContext());
```

The first time I run the network call it works just fine, data is returned. The second time I run the network call (I have run break points through here) it gets to the HttpResponse object, runs the network call, but then immediately jumps to the `IOException` catch.

the `post` object has the same data every time, the cookies are all included.

I'm not around anybody knowledgeable about the server (running drupal), but it seems like a server issue.

Can someone shed light on why this would happen? Why would I be prohibited from getting data back a second time?

To shed further light on things, if I break through the response object, I can see it may return `""` instead of data.  if that helps at all

```
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094): ObjectService
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at com.fivepoints.service.ObjectService.getObject(ObjectService.java:121)
 05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):  at com.fivepoints.model.team.TeamView$ActivityListTask.doInBackground(TeamView.java:94)
 05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):  at com.fivepoints.model.team.TeamView$ActivityListTask.doInBackground(TeamView.java:1)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'http://mysite.com/demoObject/_c'
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectHandler.java:173)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:903)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:468)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-15 11:22:34.612: E/(1094):   ... 10 more
```

Comment: What is the exception it throws?

Comment: I know but IOException covers all IO Exceptions.  What does the LogCat say.

Comment: hm I'm currently not `Log.e` anything. `} catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("myService", e.getMessage());` returns a null exception

Comment: Please post the actual EXCEPTION, in its entirety. The stack trace will tell you the exact line of code that caused the crash. Open your logcat view in Eclipse, and copy the 50-100 line stack trace that is usually in Red. Telling us you have an IOException without POSTING the entire exception is useless.

Comment: @jack thats because it doesn't tell me anything, it just tells me that it gets an error in the asynctask, and then it tells me about the null pointer exception from not getting any data back from the http response. I'm adding something to my `catch` statement to get more info

Comment: If you are using Eclipse look in the `Debug` or `DDMS` perspectives to view the `LogCat`.

Comment: e = `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException`

Comment: Does every HTTP request after the first cause an exception?

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException`

Comment: @techiServices I am deducing that now

Comment: @techiServices thanks for helping me get to the bottom of it with logcat, this `http://stackoverflow.com/a/6699772/727429` is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the way I was logging errors also caused a crash, so I didn't know what the exact error was.

The real exception was `Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException` because the way the server handles API calls

This is the answer from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6699772/727429

`HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);`