# How to use loopj-async-http android library on Intentservice?

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I am trying to create connections using the SyncClient provided with

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

I am not able to connect to my Webservice, it shows me the following logs

```
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:75)
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:94)
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:56)
12-05 19:54:45.397: W/System.err(3836):     at com.loopj.android.http.SyncHttpClient.sendRequest(SyncHttpClient.java:66)
12-05 19:54:45.407: W/System.err(3836):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(AsyncHttpClient.java:340)
12-05 19:54:45.407: W/System.err(3836):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(AsyncHttpClient.java:329)
12-05 19:54:45.407: W/System.err(3836):     at net.connectedu.service.AlarmService.checkAppStatus(AlarmService.java:151)
12-05 19:54:45.407: W/System.err(3836):     at net.connectedu.service.AlarmService.doWakefulWork(AlarmService.java:146)
12-05 19:54:45.407: W/System.err(3836):     at com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService.onHandleIntent(WakefulIntentService.java:108)
12-05 19:54:45.407: W/System.err(3836):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
12-05 19:54:45.418: W/System.err(3836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 19:54:45.418: W/System.err(3836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 19:54:45.418: W/System.err(3836):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
12-05 19:54:45.418: W/System.err(3836): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'https://localhost/api/get_logs/lalith/'
12-05 19:54:45.427: W/System.err(3836):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectHandler.java:173)
12-05 19:54:45.427: W/System.err(3836):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:923)
12-05 19:54:45.437: W/System.err(3836):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:475)
12-05 19:54:45.437: W/System.err(3836):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-05 19:54:45.437: W/System.err(3836):     ... 14 more
```

What would be the possible reasons for this ? does the synchronous library in loopj works fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to use the synchronous library in loopj-android http lib : below is the example. I am able to get response for the first time the alarm is triggered but I get the above code the next time the alarm reciever is scheduled. Hope to find some answers :(

```
String content = ConnectionManager.getSyncClient.get("http://www.google.com");
```

the next time the request comes I get the exception above. :(

I found  the error in the library, it doesnt allow circular redirections. I guess, there would be someone else who has similar problem. I found this post helpful,

[Avoid Circular Redirect using HttpClient 4.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698214/avoid-circular-redirect-using-httpclient-4-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your request isnt sent to a proxy before being sent your requested url. I've discovered that some mobile service providers applies content adaption or content morphing to all your requests to ensure that the requested sites are adapted for mobile views, which means your request isnt properly redirected from the proxy. You can check the internet settings on your mobile device to make sure your connection isnt redirected via a proxy.

This can be found under **wireless & network settings** -> **mobile networks** -> **access point names** -> and then your selected internet item

Since you seem to be using localhost you can also try and bypass the error like this:

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.getHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);

If you are receiving a response back that needs to be parsed and you get a parsing exception and assuming your parsing code is correct, it is more than likely because you are receiving a response back from the proxy server and not the requested one